# memory corruption while executing my code

Tags: visual-c++

```
    # include "stdafx.h"
    # include <iostream>
    #include <ctype.h>
    using  namespace std;
    class a
    {
    protected:
        int d;
    public: 
        virtual void assign(int A) = 0;
        int get();
    };

    class b : a
    {   
        char* n;
    public:
        b()
        {
        n=NULL;
        }
        virtual ~b()
        {
        delete n;
        }
        void assign(int A)
        {
            d=A;
        } 
        void assignchar(char *c)
        {
            n=c;
        }
        int get()
        {
            return d;
        }
        char* getchart()
        {
                return n;
        }
    };

    class c : b
    {
        b *pB;
        int e;
    public:
        c()
        {
                pB=new b();
        }
        ~c()
        {
                delete pB;
        }
        void assign(int A)
        {
                e=A;
                pB->assign(A);
            }
        int get()
        {
            return e;
        }
        b* getp()
        {
            return pB;
        }
    };

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
                    c *pC=new c();
                    pC->assign(10);
                    b *p=pC->getp();
                    p->assignchar("a");
                char *abc=p->getchart();
                delete pC;
                    cout<<*abc<<endl;
                getchar();
    }
```

i'm a noob at c++ and was experimenting when i got to this point. I don't understand why i keep getting a memory corruption message from VS2010. I am trying to replicate a problem which is at a higher level by breaking it down into smaller bits, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a cursory glance, you are passing a static char array to AssignChar that cannot be deleted (ie when you type "A" into your code, its a special block of memory the compiler allocates for you).

You need to understand what assignment of a char* does (or any pointer to type). When you call `n=c` you are just assigning the pointer, the memory that pointer points to remains where it is. So, unless this is exactly what you meant to do, you will have 2 pointers pointing to the same block of memory.. and you need to decide which to delete (you can't delete it twice, that'd be bad).

My advice here is to start using C++, so no more char* types, use std::string instead. Using char* is C programming. Note that if you did use a std::string, and passed one to `assignChars`, it would copy as you expected (and there is no need to free std::string objects in your destructor, they handle all that for you).

Comment: isn't passing a std::string to the assignchar() function equivalent to passing the first character of that string?

Comment: I would think you'd want n to be a std::string too. Think of it as a encapsulated string type.. which is what it is. If you want to deal with char* then instead of copying the pointer, you need strdup().

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you're trying to delete `pC`.

When `~c()` destructor calls `~b()` destructor - you're trying to `delete n;`.

The problem is that after `assignchar()`, `n` points to a string literal which was given to it as an argument (`"a"`).

That string is not dynamically allocated, and should not be freed, meaning you should either remove the 'delete n;' line, or give a dynamically-allocated string to `assignchar()` as an argument.